# ProGuard error while exporting android project with Support Library

Tags: java, android, apk, proguard, android-support-library

I am having troubles with exporting project in eclipse. I built my app on top of zxing's Barcode Scanner and when I try to export I get this enormously big error log:

```
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find superclass or interface android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1: can't find superclass or interface android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1: can't find superclass or interface android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs$1: can't find superclass or interface android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$AccessibilityStateChangeListener
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatJellyBean$1: can't find superclass or interface android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompatHoneycomb$1: can't find superclass or interface android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'boolean getCanRetrieveWindowContent()' in class android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getDescription()' in class android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo
---- even more lines here, but i touched SO lines limit :) ----
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcsMr1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcsMr1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcsMr1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcsMr1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcsMr1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.widget.EdgeEffect
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.widget.EdgeEffect
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.widget.EdgeEffect
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.widget.EdgeEffect
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.widget.EdgeEffect
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.widget.EdgeEffect
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.widget.EdgeEffect
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.widget.EdgeEffect
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.widget.EdgeEffect
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.widget.EdgeEffect
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.ScrollerCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'float getCurrVelocity()' in class android.widget.Scroller
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompatHoneycomb: can't find referenced class android.widget.SearchView
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompatHoneycomb: can't find referenced class android.widget.SearchView
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompatHoneycomb: can't find referenced class android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompatHoneycomb: can't find referenced class android.widget.SearchView
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompatHoneycomb$1: can't find referenced class android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompatHoneycomb$1: can't find referenced class android.widget.SearchView
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: there were 269 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Warning: there were 55 unresolved references to program class members.
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-02-12 18:25:23 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

When i add this line to my proguard.cfg:

```
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

I get this:

```
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]   Class       = [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl]
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]   Method      = [newAccessiblityDelegateBridge(Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat;)Ljava/lang/Object;]
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]   Instruction = [18] areturn
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find any super classes of [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1] (not even immediate super class [android/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate]))
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]   Class       = [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl]
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]   Method      = [newAccessiblityDelegateBridge(Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat;)Ljava/lang/Object;]
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find any super classes of [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1] (not even immediate super class [android/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate]))
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find any super classes of [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1] (not even immediate super class [android/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate])
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:287)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.evaluation.value.IdentifiedReferenceValue.generalize(IdentifiedReferenceValue.java:65)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:481)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.optimize.info.MethodOptimizationInfo.generalizeReturnValue(MethodOptimizationInfo.java:247)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.optimize.evaluation.StoringInvocationUnit.generalizeMethodReturnValue(StoringInvocationUnit.java:195)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.optimize.evaluation.StoringInvocationUnit.setMethodReturnValue(StoringInvocationUnit.java:126)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.evaluation.BasicInvocationUnit.exitMethod(BasicInvocationUnit.java:134)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.evaluation.Processor.visitSimpleInstruction(Processor.java:514)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.classfile.instruction.SimpleInstruction.accept(SimpleInstruction.java:218)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateSingleInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:753)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:587)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlockAndExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:560)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:264)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:181)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:116)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:372)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115)
[2013-02-12 18:19:30 - com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

My proguard.cfg file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*



-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok guys, i found it. Basically you have to remove all your jar dependenicies in project setup, then clean project and that's it! My hair turned gray today and I got neurosis. Oh, and this is needed:

```
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

You should build against a version of the Android platform that contains the mentioned classes. For instance, android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord only exists as of android-14.

You can still specify different minimum versions and target versions in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to export a release, consider disabling Proguard temporarily:

- 1) edit project.properties , comment out the proguard.config=
- 2) rename the proguard dir under
- 3) rename the proguard*.cfg files